# how do I change the splune type line to vertical columns?

Tags: javascript

1. How do I make the horizontal green lines disappear after the price rises to a certain value? For example, the first disappears at a price of 5000, and the second at a price of 50,000.
2. How to make a black line in the form of columns?
3. How to create exponential acceleration? I subtracted values from DURATION in the loop, but very sharp jumps occur.
   view the script in progress: https://yofa.ru/index2.html

   ```js
   let globalData = [];
   let finRez = [];
   let chart;

   let duration = 500; // Determines how long the animation between new points should be take
   let startIterator = 1; // Determines how many points will be rendered on chart's init
   let currentIterator = startIterator;
   let maxIterator = 1;

   let guiButton = document.getElementById('start');
   let guiButtonState = 'Start';
   let intervalId;

   // Fetch data:
   fetch('https://yofa.ru/1.json')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
       parseData(data);
       createChart();
       initEvents();
     });

   function initEvents() {
     guiButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       if (guiButtonState === 'Stop') {
         // User clicked "Stop" -> stop animation and allow to resume
         intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
         guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Resume';
       } else {
         // If animation has finished, recreate chart
         if (guiButtonState === 'Restart') {
           createChart();
         }
         guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Stop';
         // Start animation:
         redrawChart(currentIterator += 1);
         intervalId = setInterval(function() {
           // If we reached last available point, stop animation:
           if (currentIterator === maxIterator) {
             intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
             currentIterator = startIterator;
             guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Restart';
           } else {
             redrawChart(currentIterator += 1);
           }
         }, duration);
       }
     });
   }

   function redrawChart(index) {
     // Set new subtitle on every redraw
     chart.setTitle(null, {
       text: ' Заработано: ' + globalData[0].data[index][1] + '<br>Финрез: ' + globalData[1].data[index][1]
     }, false);


     const newValues = globalData.map(series => series.data[index][1]);
     const maxIndex = newValues.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, newValues));

     // To each series, add a point:
     chart.series.forEach(
       (series, seriesIndex) => {
         const enabled = maxIndex === seriesIndex && ((index < 5) || (index % 5 === 0));
         series.addPoint({
             name: getFormattedDate(globalData[seriesIndex].data[index][0]),
             y: globalData[seriesIndex].data[index][1]
           },
           false,
           false,
           false
         );
       }
     );

     // Now, once everything is updated, redraw chart:
     chart.redraw({
       duration
     });
   }

   function getFormattedDate(date) {
     const dateObj = new Date(date);

     return dateObj.getDate() + '-' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dateObj.getFullYear()
   }

   function parseData(data) {
     Highcharts.objectEach(
       data,
       // Prepare Highcharts data-format:
       // series: [{
       //   data: [ [x, y], [x, y], ..., [x, y]]
       // }]
       (countryData, country) => {
         if (country !== 'Diamond Princess' && country !== 'Holy See') {
           globalData.push({
             name: country,
             data: countryData.map(p => [Date.parse(p.date), p.recovered / getCountryPopulation(country)])
           });
         }

       }
     );


     // Sort and limit dataset:
     globalData = globalData
       .sort((countryA, countryB) => {
         let countryALen,
           countryBLen;

         if (!countryA || !countryA.data || countryA.data.length === 0) {
           return 1;
         }

         if (!countryB || !countryB.data || countryB.data.length === 0) {
           return -1;
         }

         return countryB.data[countryB.data.length - 1][1] - countryA.data[countryA.data.length - 1][1]
       })
       .splice(0, 8);


     maxIterator = Math.max.apply(null, globalData.map(series => series.data.length - 1));
   }


   function createChart() {
     function format(y) {
       return y.toFixed(2);
     }
    
     chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
       chart: {
         type: 'spline',
         marginLeft: 100
       },

       legend: {
         layout: 'proximate',
         align: 'right'
       },


       title: {
         floating: true,
         align: 'left',
         x: 93,
         y: 20,
         text: 'График роста'
       },
       subtitle: {
         floating: true,
         align: 'left',
         y: 60,
         x: 90,
         text: ' Заработано: ' + globalData[0].data[0][1] + "<br>Финрез: " + globalData[1].data[0][1],
         style: {
           fontSize: '20px'
         }
       },
       tooltip: {
         split: true,
         pointFormatter: function() {
         }
       },

       yAxis: {
         title: {
           text: ''
         },
         maxPadding: 0.2,
         softMax: 1,
         
       plotLines: [{
           color: 'red',
           width: 2,
           value: 0,
           zIndex: 0
           
       }   ,{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 1000,
           zIndex: 0,
           label:{text:'Собираю спред'},

       },{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 5000,
           zIndex: 0,
           label:{text:'Пробую фьючерсы'}
       },{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 10000,
           zIndex: 0,
           label:{text:'Торгую всё'}
       },{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 50000,
           zIndex: 0,
           label:{text:'Торгую только фьючерсы'}
       },{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 100000,
           zIndex: 0,
           label:{text:'Пробую валюту'}
       },{
           color: 'green',
           width: 2,
           value: 500000,
           zIndex: 5,
           label:{text:'Торгую только валюту'}
       }
       ]
       },

       xAxis: {
         gridLineWidth: 1,
         type: 'category'
       },


       plotOptions: {
         series: {
           animation: {
             duration
           },
           marker: {
               enabled: false
           },
           dataLabels: {
             formatter: function() {
               return format(this.y);
             }
           }
         }
       },
       series: globalData.map(series => {
         return {
           name: series.name,
           data: series.data.slice(0, startIterator).map(point => {
             return {
               name: getFormattedDate(point[0]),
               y: point[1]
             }
           })
         }
       })
     });
   }


   function getCountryPopulation(country) {
     return {
       "Заработано": 1,
       "Финансовый результат": 1
     } [country];
   }
   ```

   ```css
   #container {
     min-width: 800px;
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 600px;
   }

   #outer-container {
     max-width: 1200px;
     min-width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 600px;
   }

   #outer-container .controls {
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }


   #outer-container button {
       margin: 0 auto;
       color: #fff;
       background-color: #007bff;
       border-color: #007bff;
       border: 1px solid transparent;
       padding: .375rem .75rem;
       font-size: 1rem;
       line-height: 1.5;
       border-radius: .25rem;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

   <div id="outer-container">

     <div class="controls">
       <button id="start">
         Start
       </button>
     </div>
     
     <div id="container"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to focus on one specific question at a time and give a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hi. focus: How do I make the horizontal green lines disappear after the price rises to a certain value? For example, the first disappears at a price of 5000, and the second at a price of 50,000.